# Notepad++ replace blank space with 0 in csv

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have one CSV file with data like below.

```
ABC,XYZ,LMN
0,,2.3
3.4,3,5
,0,
1.3,,4.5
```

Is there any way to replace the empty column with a 0 value using `Regex`?

EDIT: Tried **Tim Biegeleisen** solution like below

```
Find:    (^|,)(,|$)
Replace: ${1}0${2}
```

But it doesn't work in below case. If I have CSV data like below

```
ABC,XYZ,LMN
0,,2.3
3.4,3,5
,,0 // here it doesn't work
1.3,,
```

Comment: Don't know how would your result look like, I think,  you should to search for `''` and replace it with  `'0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Find:    (?<![^,\r\n])(?=,|$)
(or)     (?:,|^)\K(?=,|$)
Replace: 0
```

*Details*:

- `(?<![^,\r\n])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is no `,`, CR or LF char immediately on the left (basically, it is roughly `(?<=,|^)`, a comma or start of a line must occur immediately to the left of the current location)
- `(?:,|^)\K` - matches a comma or start of a line and `\K` removes the comma (if matched) from the match value (it is a kind of a lookbehind alternative)
- `(?=,|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires either `,` or end of a line immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3XxtCY/1):

[image]